# Skips a line after iteration

Tags: java, iteration

So i have this simple code in java. But when i tried to **"use the program again"** as written in the code, it always skips the first entry which is to **Enter the name**. How do i fix this?

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Try{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int salary;
    String name, perform;
    int choice = 1;
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter your name:");     
        name=sc.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Enter your performance:");  
        perform=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your salary:");   
        salary=sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Name: "+name);
        System.out.println("Performance: " + perform);
        System.out.println("Salary:" + salary);

        System.out.println("Do you want to use the program again?\n[1]Yes\n[2]No"); 
        choice=sc.nextInt();
    }while (choice < 2);
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `sc.nextLine()` after `nextInt()`, because nextInt() doesn't consume the line break (unlike nextLine()). So there's always an extra linebreak waiting at the beginning of the loop (after the first iteration).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
salary=Integer.parseInt( sc.nextLine() );
```

and

```
choice = Integer.parseInt( sc.nextLine() );
```

instead of using `sc.nextInt();`

You also need to consider wrapping those lines with `try{} catch(...)` blocks to avoid inputs other than integers.